# listview/adapterview only shows 1 value in all fields

Tags: java, android

I'm building my first app but I'm having troubles with 1 piece of the code.
When a value is added (in this case a recipe) it saving the name and the the recipe itself.
The name is listed in a listview which is working.
But when I click the value I want to show/edit/delete, it also shows the name in the recipe field.
Can somebody help me / point me in the right direction?

The code is still messy:

My Recipe Listview
    public class Recipes extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "Recipes";

DatabaseRecipes mDatabaseRecipes;
ArrayList<RecipeHelper> recipeList;
ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes);
    recipeList = new ArrayList<>();
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mDatabaseRecipes = new DatabaseRecipes(this);
    Cursor data = mDatabaseRecipes.getData();

    populateListView();

    Button button_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);

    button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Continue to adding Recipes");
            toastMessage("Continue to adding Recipes");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Recipes.this, AddRecipe.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

    //get the data and append to a list
    Cursor data = mDatabaseRecipes.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        //get the value from the database in column 1
        //then add it to the ArrayList
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }
    //create the list adapter and set the adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            String recipe = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);

            Cursor data = mDatabaseRecipes.getData(); //get the id associated with that name
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if(itemID > -1){
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                Intent editScreenIntent = new Intent(Recipes.this, EditRecipe.class);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                editScreenIntent.putExtra("recipe",recipe);
                startActivity(editScreenIntent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that ingredient");
            }
        }
});
}

/**
 * customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

My edit recipe:
    public class EditRecipe extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "EditRecipe";

private Button button_edit,button_delete,button_back;
public EditText editRecipe, editRecipeName;

DatabaseRecipes mDatabaseRecipe;

private String selectedName, selectedRecipe;
private int selectedID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_recipe);
    button_edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
    button_delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    button_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    editRecipeName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRecipeName);
    editRecipe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRecipe);
    mDatabaseRecipe = new DatabaseRecipes(this);

    //get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();

    //now get the itemID we passed as an extra
    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value

    //now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

    //now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedRecipe = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("recipe");

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    editRecipeName.setText(selectedName);

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    editRecipe.setText(selectedRecipe);

    button_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String item = editRecipeName.getText().toString();
            String item2 = editRecipe.getText().toString();
            if(!item.equals("") && !item2.equals("")){
                mDatabaseRecipe.updateName(item,selectedID,selectedName);
                mDatabaseRecipe.updateRecipe(item2,selectedID,selectedRecipe);
                Intent int1 = new Intent(EditRecipe.this, Recipes.class);
                startActivity(int1);
            }else{
                toastMessage("You must enter a name");
            }
        }
    });

    button_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mDatabaseRecipe.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
            editRecipeName.setText("");
            toastMessage("removed from database");
            Intent int1 = new Intent(EditRecipe.this, Recipes.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }
    });

    button_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(EditRecipe.this, Recipes.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * customizable toast
 * @param message
 */
private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

My editrecipe.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editIngredient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="284dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="256dp"
    android:background="@color/black_overlay"
    android:ems="10"

    android:inputType="text|textPersonName"
    android:text="@string/ingredient"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button-recipes" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_edit"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:text="@string/edit_the_ingredient"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_delete"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:text="@string/delete_the_ingredient"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_back"
    android:layout_width="182dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
    android:text="@string/Back"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have the github code, maybe one can help debug it from there. I did this project on the udacity nano degree Google scholarship.

Comment: @Madonah Syombua I don't have a github yet. I preffer to learn first what I did wrong / how it can be done better / good, after that I want to publish the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onItemCLickListener, you are doing:

```
String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
String recipe = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

Exact same function for the two variables, so likely you are getting twice the same information

I don't know how your Recipe class looks, but maybe you want something more like

```
String name = recipesList.get(i).getName(); 
String recipe = recipesList.get(i).getRecipe();
```

Edit:
After reading more carefully I realize you are not creating your listview using the recipesList but the listData list. You are populating it with the results of your cursor but only the fist column each time, so I assume it's always the name. You are not storing your recipe anywhere, you will have to if you want to be able to retrieve it when clicking on an item.

Assuming your Recipe class contains name and recipe, and your database has one column for name and one for recipe, you can do something like this:

```
Cursor data = mDatabaseRecipes.getData();
ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
while(data.moveToNext()){
    //get the value from the database in column 1
    //then add it to the ArrayList
    listData.add(data.getString(1));
    recipesList.add(new Recipe(data.get(NAME_COLUMN), data.get(RECIPE_COLUMN));
}
```

Then it should work without making too much changes to your code. But ideally you should use only one list if possible.

Comment: I understand :) I changed it but now the app crashes when I click a recipe.

Comment: Sorry I missed something the first time I read the post, I edited my answer

Comment: Unfortunally the code isn't working.
I added the code, changed it but the new recipe/Recipe isn't working.

Comment: @Koetjeboe What is not working exactly, could you give some more details?

Comment: I recplaced the listData with recipeData, but then I got the error on     String name = recipesList.get(i).getName(); that the variable is accessed from within the inner class. With the listData it won't load and the app will crash.

And the function recipesList.add(new Recipe(data.get(name), data.get(recipe)); is only showing that everything doens't exist (the red texts)

Comment: For the first error, would you be able to share the piece of code that is doing that? For the recipelist.add error, sorry that wasn't really clear. You have to replace NAME_COLUMN and RECIPE_COLUMN by the number of the corresponding column in your db. For instance, if your database table has id, name, recipe in that order, you'll have to do recipesList.add(new Recipe(data.get(1), data.get(2));

Comment: I understand I needed to replace those values to make it work, but the (new recipe) won't work.I uploaded the complete project to github: https://github.com/Koetjeboeh/RecipeCreator, maybe it's easier?

Comment: Thanks it's indeed easier to see, however the code seems to be the same as what you have in your post, so I'm not able to see where that new issue is coming from. One thing I notice though is that your RecipeHelper class is actually the same as the Recipe class I was suggesting, so you can use that RecipeHelper in the recipeList.add

Comment: I see the only thing is not working is the intent. The values of the name and the calue of the recipe wont send over. If I replace the string with a hard value (Test 1) the app is working like it should. (Recipes.java line 75 and 76).